# Is this simple oscillatory integral operator uniformly bounded on $L^2$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Let $\phi(t,s)$ be a real-valued function smooth away from the diagonal, and equal to 0 on the diagonal. Assume that $0\le \phi(t,s)\le |t-s|$ for $t,s\in \mathbb{R}$. Let
$$T_\lambda f(t)=\int \frac{\sin(\lambda\phi(t,s))}{|t-s|}f(s)ds,\ \lambda\gg1$$
Then do we have the uniform bound $$||T_\lambda||_{L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]}\le C,$$
where $C$ is a constant independent of $\lambda$?

For example, if $\phi(t,s)=|t-s|$, it is well known that the answer is YES, by the multiplier theorem. Indeed, $\frac{\sin(\lambda(t-s))}{t-s}$ is essentially the Dirichlet kernel for the partial summation of one-dimensional Fourier series. But I don't know whether this simple generalization has been considered before.

Any comments are welcome;) I will be grateful if you can point out some related references to me. Thanks!

Comment: Isn't it false if $\phi$ is constant away from the diagonal ?

Comment: @SimonHenry  "Assume that $0\le \phi(t,s)\le |t-s|$"

Comment: That does not prevent $\phi$ from being constant 'away from the diagonal', like $\phi(t,s)= min(1,|t-s|)$.

Comment: @SimonHenry I am not sure... We can only consider the operator on $L^2[0,1]$, for simplicity.

Comment: what if $\varphi(t,s)=\max(t-s,0)$?

Comment: Let $\phi(t,s) = \psi(t-s)$. Let $\lambda$ be fixed and $\delta$ small. If $\psi(t-s) \in (\delta/\lambda , (\pi - \delta)\lambda)$, then we have a convolution with a positive kernel. Such convolutions are bounded either for all $L^p$ or for none. Since it is a singular integral, the first case cannot take place.

Comment: @Almaz: This scenario is not possible under the OP's assumption that $0\le \psi \le |t-s|$.